# 3d hover/move on image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found a cool effect, when a user hovers on the image, the image moves around/tilting, giving a cool 3D effect. I added an example link below (hover over skull image in the link to see the effect).

Does anyone know how to do this affect? I researched but couldnt find the code, I want to try this effect. I would really appreciate any answer. Thank you

[Link to example](https://conference.awwwards.com/speakers?utm_campaign=awwwards&utm_source=banner-4)

Comment: It is done using a CSS transformation called `matrix3d`, feel free to google for it.

Comment: thanks so much for the information! I see the                                                                             code. But I cant see anything on hover. When I hovered and inspect element, I only see element matrix that changes as I hover around. Is there another code (hover code)? This is the only code I found when i see the effect element.style {
    transform: matrix3d(0.995073, 0, -0.0991457, 0.000247864, 0.00240588, 0.999706, 0.0241466, -6.03665e-05, 0.0991166, -0.0242661, 0.99478, -0.00248695, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform-origin: center 50% 0px;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a number of ways to achieve this effect, I believe the one presented in code below is one of the simplest. It utilizes CSS transform `rotate3d` instead of the more complicated `matrix3d` mentioned above and used in the original example. For more details on the solution, please see comments in code.

**Disclaimer:** The code below is provided for reference only, might not be completely compliant with best industry best practices and might not be suitable for production use. It has been tested in Google Chrome version 57.0.2987.133 and might rely on features not supported in other or older browsers.

***HTML***

```
<div id="tracking-area">
  <div id="transformation-area">

  </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
body {
    //  Padding & margins
    margin: 0;

    //  Background
    background-color: silver;
}

#tracking-area {
    //  Display & position
    position: relative;

    //  Dimensions
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;

    //  Padding & margins
    margin: 50px auto;

    //  Border
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

#transformation-area {
    //  Display & position
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;

    //  Dimensions
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;

    //  Background
    background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/00/7d/d2/007dd2a468e9a453da691e8e7a383973.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

***JavaScript***

```
//  The following two numbers define the angles (in degrees)
//  that the transformation area will be rotated at about
//  X and Y axes when the cursor reaches the right (for Y) 
//  and the top (for X) borders of the tracking area.
var maxRotationDegreesX = 60;
var maxRotationDegreesY = 60;

//  This effectively defines the distance along X axis between
//  the reference point and the projection plane. The greater the 
//  number, the greater the transformation area's projection
//  is deformed due to perspective.
var perspectivePx = 600;

$(document).ready(function () {   
    //  These variables are requried to translate screen coordinates 
    //  supplied by mouse event into the coordinate system with 
    //  its reference point placed in the center of the tracking area.
    var trackingAreaShiftX = $("#tracking-area").offset().left;
    var trackingAreaShiftY = $("#tracking-area").offset().top;

    var halfTrackingAreaWidth = $("#tracking-area").width() / 2;
    var halfTrackingAreaHeight = $("#tracking-area").height() / 2;

    var mouseCoordinateCorrectionX = trackingAreaShiftX + halfTrackingAreaWidth;
    var mouseCoordinateCorrectionY = trackingAreaShiftY + halfTrackingAreaHeight;

    $("#tracking-area").on("mousemove", function () {
        //  Translate cooridnates of the mouse ponter 
        var x = event.clientX - mouseCoordinateCorrectionX;
        var y = event.clientY - mouseCoordinateCorrectionY;
        //  Calculate degrees of rotation with respect to their maximum values
        var rotationY = x * maxRotationDegreesX / halfTrackingAreaWidth;
        var rotationX = -y * maxRotationDegreesY / halfTrackingAreaHeight;
        //  Construct CSS transform setting string
        var transform = `perspective(${perspectivePx}px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, ${rotationX}deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, ${rotationY}deg)`;
        //  Apply the transformation
        $("#transformation-area").css("-webkit-transform", transform);
        $("#transformation-area").css("-moz-transform", transform);
        $("#transformation-area").css("-ms-transform", transform);
        $("#transformation-area").css("-o-transform", transform);
        $("#transformation-area").css("transform", transform);
    });
});
```

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/eduard-malakhov/pen/mmJwbZ